# Strange icon on network

Tags: networking, icons

Wired network is working, but I see a strange icon, what does it mean?

[image: Network icon is showing as three dots between brackets]

[image: The same as previous image]

Network icon is showing as three dots between brackets

Previous network icon:

[image: Old network icon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the default wired connection icon form the [specially designed elementary icons set](https://github.com/elementary/icons), nothing to worry about.

Comment: So it must have changed.

Comment: @Edney you can read here about the reasons that lead to the changing of that particular icon: https://github.com/elementary/icons/pull/732